# Use Css3 Transform on remote elements

Tags: css

I am designing a website in which I would like to animate an image from hovering over remote links.

The idea is I have a div with a dive nested inside containing an image, a clock hand.

When the user hovers over the "home" link the hand should rotate 30 degrees so that it will point to a home section of the clock.

I need for each link to rotate the remote clock hand image a certain number of degrees for each link.
I can get this to work hovering over the hand itself, its making it work remotely that I can't seem to figure out.

any ideas?